# Program doesn't perform looping

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

```
bool correct = false;
while (!correct)
{
    cout << "Please enter an angle value => ";
    cin >> value; //request user to input a value

    if(cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        while(cin.get() != '\n');
             correct = false;
    }
    else
        cin.get();
    cin.ignore();
    correct = true;
}
```

Here's my problem according to the code above:

1. After I input a value, the program will pause and I have to press enter again to proceed to next part of the program; how can I avoid it?
2. Besides, if I enter value like 'abcd', program will not loop to request user to input value again, why is it so?
   Instead, it will still proceed and output a value of 0.

I'm still new to these kind of command, just playing and explore them, I appreciate your guides!

edit:

```
while (!correct)
    {
        cout << "Please enter an angle value => ";
        cin >> value; //request user to input a value

        if(cin.fail())
        {
        cin.clear();
        while(cin.get() != '\n');
        correct = false;

        }
        else
        {
        cin.get();
        cin.ignore();
        correct = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use brackets regardless of how many line are in the scope. This will make it easier to read.

Comment: Since the code unconditionally sets `correct` to `true` (once it is indented to reflect the actual structure), your loop stops.  Did you forget the `{ ... }` around the `else` clause?  I worry about what happens once you get EOF (for example, the user redirects standard input from `/dev/null`).  I think you end up with an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

You set `correct=true` unconditionally on the very first iteration, and bail out of the loop. Looks like you meant to add a pair of braces around the three statements after `else`.

Comment: Thanks! sorry, I don't get your mean that my correct=trure is unconditionally?

Comment: Look at the original code.  The last statement before the end of the `while` loop is `correct = true;`, and it is always executed.  Incidentally, I note that you have `while (cin.get() != '\n');` which has a null statement after the loop, which means the indentation of `correct = false;` is incorrect, and you can run into problems if the input is coming from `/dev/null`.  I said that before, but you now hit an even tighter loop than I originally thought.